# yii2 нужно связать две таблицы по полю id, но выводить name связанной

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование, yii2

Есть модель первой таблицы OneTable:

```
'id' => 'ID',
'user_id' => 'Пользователь',
'message' => 'Сообщение'
```

Вторая модель связываемой таблицы User:

```
'id' => 'Код сотрудника',
 'username' => 'Имя пользователя'
```

В первой модели сделал такую связь:

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
```

В контроллере, для представления этого crud'a:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new OneTableSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

В index.php:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
                'attribute' => 'id',
                'value' => 'id',
                'headerOptions'=> ['style'=>'width: 10px'],
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'user_id',
                'label' => 'Пользователь',
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],

                'headerOptions'=> ['style'=>'width: 10px'],
                'value' => '????',
// Собственно, вот здесь я не могу понять что нужно написать.  Нужно как-то использовать связывающий метод?
            ],
          'message',

            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template'=>'{view}'
            ],  
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

**Таблицы в базе изначально не связаны**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего так:

```
'value' => function($model) {
    return $model->user->name;
}
```

Потому что в `value` можно писать callback функцию с возвращаемым значением

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn#$value-detail

Comment: Благодарю! Получилось именно так, как и хотел
(+ не могу поставить из-за низкого уровня репутации)

Comment: Атрибут user_id является числом, выводится мне string (номер пользователя меняется на его ФИО), и в фильтрации теперь теперь нужно изменить валидацию? Фильтрация требует номер юзера, а возможно ли вводить имя?
Скорее всего это можно прописать в модели или в searchmodel

Comment: @Pvokinsark да, пишется теперь всё в searchmodel. https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-sortirovka-i-filtr-gridview-po-svyazannym-i-vychislyaemym-polyam.html, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176506/6138795  в общем поиск по связанным полям надо искать в поисковике))